# How to jump from "Emacs Command History" to "Emacs Commands" in helm

Tags: helm

I'm using Prelude. When I press `M-x`, I get `helm-M-x`. Recently I've used `query-replace-regexp`. Now when I type "replace-regexp", it automatically reaches for element in my history. There is separate section for commands below, where my beloved `replace-regexp` is, but I don't know how to reach it. How can I get in there and use the command I want to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `C-n` (`helm-next-line`) to move line-wise or `C-o`/`<right>` (`helm-next-source`) to move source-wise.

See the [Basic Usage](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm#basic-usage) section of the Helm guide for more info:

> Once you are in the helm session (of `helm-M-x` or any one else) you can hit either `C-h m` or `C-c ?`, the former is will popup a general info buffer about helm while the second will popup a specialized info of the current source you are into.

`C-h m` will give you a nice basic hotkey table and plenty of more info.

Comment: Per the Helm `M-x` help "Helm's basic operation and default keybindings" table: Although 'C-o` does work, `C-n` does *not* do what the OP requested, but cycles back around to top of command history.  `<right>` is not defined by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem until I noticed that I had `helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source` set to `t`.  I set it to `nil` and this problem vanished.